# Makefile Compiling Issue for Mixed C++ and Fortran Program

Tags: c++, makefile, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

**This is my makefile :**

```
    PROGRAM = mf2005-GPU.f

    # Define the Fortran compile flags
    F90FLAGS= -g -fopenmp
    F90= gfortran

    # Define the C compile flags
    # -D_UF defines UNIX naming conventions for mixed language compilation.
    CFLAGS= -D_UF -O3
    CC= gcc

    CPPFLAGS= -Dcpp_variable
    CXX= g++

    # Define GMG objects
    #
    GMG = r_vector.o\
      solvers.o\
      ccfd.o\
      mf2kgmg.o\

    # Define the libraries

    SYSLIBS= -lc
    USRLIB  = 
    CUDA_LIB64=/cm/shared/apps/cuda40/toolkit/4.0.17/lib64/
    LFLAGS = -L$(CUDA_LIB64) -lcuda -lcudart -lcusparse -lcublas -lpthread -lm -lcufft -lcurand -lnpp -lgomp 

    # Define all object files which make up MODFLOW

    OBJECTS = \
    dblas.o\
    gwf2bas7.o \
    de47.o \
    dlapak.o\
    pcg7.o \
    sip7.o \
    gmg7.o \
    mhc7.o \
    gwf2bcf7.o \
    gwf2lpf7.o \
    gwf2huf7.o \
    gwf2rch7.o \
    gwfuzfmodule.o \
    gwfsfrmodule.o \
    gwf2lak7.o \
    gwf2sfr7.o \
    gwf2uzf1.o \
    gwf2gag7.o \
    gwf2chd7.o \
    gwf2drn7.o \
    gwf2drt7.o \
    gwf2ets7.o \
    gwf2evt7.o \
    gwf2fhb7.o \
    gwf2ghb7.o \
    gwf2hfb7.o \
    gwf2ibs7.o \
    gwf2res7.o \
    gwf2riv7.o \
    gwf2str7.o \
    gwf2sub7.o \
    gwf2swt7.o \
    gwf2wel7.o \
    hufutl7.o \
    obs2bas7.o \
    obs2drn7.o \
    obs2ghb7.o \
    obs2riv7.o \
    obs2chd7.o \
    obs2str7.o \
    parutl7.o \
    gwf2mnw17.o \
    gwf2mnw27.o \
    gwf2mnw2i7.o \
    utl7.o \
    lmt7.o \
    gwf2hydmod7.o \
    upcg7.o \
    upcgc.o \
    upcg7lanczos.o \
    upcg7polya.o \
    upcg7polyu.o \
    mf2005-GPU.o \

    # Define Task Function

    all: mf2005-GPU

    # Define what mf2005

    mf2005-GPU: $(OBJECTS) $(GMG) 
-$(F90) $(F90FLAGS) -o mf2005-GPU $(OBJECTS) cuda_kernels.o $(GMG)  $(USRLIB)  $(SYSLIBS)    $(LFLAGS)

    # Object codes

    .f.o:
    $(F90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $<

    .c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<


    .cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<

    #  end
```

**This is how I compile cuda_kernels.cu**
        nvcc -c -arch sm_20 -lcuda -lcudart -lcusparse  cuda_kernels.cu

**This is what I get for errors**

```
    upcg7.o: In function `upcg7ar':
    /home/zhangmj/MF2005_MAKE/upcg7.f:731: undefined reference to `upcgc7_init_'
    upcg7.o: In function `upcg7ap':
    /home/zhangmj/MF2005_MAKE/upcg7.f:1272: undefined reference to `upcgc7_'
    upcg7.o: In function `upcg7da':
    /home/zhangmj/MF2005_MAKE/upcg7.f:1416: undefined reference to `upcgc7_final_'
    upcgc.o: In function `UPCGC7':
    upcgc.cpp:(.text+0xf6a): undefined reference to `SUPCGILU0A'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: [mf2005-GPU] Error 1 (ignored)
```

**Following is upcg7.f (this is not my code, I download it from here)**
https://github.com/jdhughes-usgs/modflow-2005-upcg/blob/master/code/src/UPCG/upcg7.f

**Following is upcgc.cpp and upcgc.h (this is not my code, I download it from here)**
https://github.com/jdhughes-usgs/modflow-2005-upcg/blob/master/code/src/UPCG/upcgc.cpp

**My question is **
SUPCGILU0A is the subroutine defined in upcg7.f. And subroutine SUPCGILU0A is called from the C++ program upcgc.cpp.
upcgc7_init, upcgc7 and upcgc7_final are defined in upcgc.cpp, And these three are called from the fortran program upcg7.f.

I understand from my research that these are likely linker issues,or C++ and Fortran need to translate some function/routine from the other, but I cannot figure out what the problem is. Is there anyone out there who might have some insight into what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

If the upcgc7 routines reside in the C code, they probably do not have the trailing underscore. The best way to deal with this is to make use of the ISO_C_BINDING interface in Fortran and declare the interfaces to these routines.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Because upcg7 routines reside in the C++ code and upcgc.cpp function reside in the Fortran code also, I have added the trailing underscore, but it doesn't work. I'll try to make use of the ISO_C_BINDING interface as what you suggested. But I was compiling under UNIX, so could ISO_C_BINDING work under UNIX?

Comment: Yes, definitely. This does not depend on the OS, but rather on the compiler you are using. If the compiler provides it, you are good to go. According to your makefile, you are using gfortran, which supports it since 2007: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Fortran2003Bind_C.